# Iterator over a vector of strings,got as input from console giving segemntation fault

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator, segmentation-fault

I have two different programs here,both of which creates a BST of strings and then checks if a given string is there in the BST.

The first program works fine when I pass the dereferencing of an iterator of the vector of strings to the find function.

But the second program fails and gives segmentation error when I take an input from the user and then pass the dereferencing of an iterator over the vector of that input string.

Why does it fail when I get an input from the user?

## Working program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    vector<std::string> vn;
    set<std::string> names;
    BST<std::string> b2;

    vn.push_back("AAA");
    vn.push_back("BBB");
    vn.push_back("CCC");

    vector<std::string>::iterator vit = vn.begin();
    for(; vit != vn.end(); vit++)
    {
         b2.insert(*vit);
         names.insert(*vit);
    }

    vit = vn.begin();
    for(; vit != vn.end(); ++vit) 
    {
         if(*(b2.find(*vit)) != *vit) 
         {
              cout << "Incorrect return value when finding " << *vit;
              return -1;
         }
    }
}
```

## Error giving program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    vector<std::string> vn;
    set<std::string> names;
    std::string cur_str;
    BST<std::string> b2;

    vn.push_back("AAA");
    vn.push_back("BBB");
    vn.push_back("CCC");


    vector<std::string>::iterator vit = vn.begin();
    for(; vit != vn.end(); vit++)
    {
         b2.insert(*vit);
         names.insert(*vit);
    }

    std::getline(std::cin, cur_str);
    vector<std::string> vn2;
    vn2.push_back(cur_str);
    vector<std::string>::iterator vit2 = vn2.begin();

    vit = vn.begin();
    for(; vit != vn.end(); ++vit) 
    {
         if(*(b2.find(*vit2)) != *vit) (gives segmentation fault in this line)
         {
              cout << "Incorrect return value when finding " << *vit << endl;
              return -1;
         }
    }
}
```

## find function

```
template<typename Data> (Declared at the beginning)
iterator find(const Data& item) const
{
    BSTNode<Data> * currentNode = root;
    while(NULL != currentNode) 
    {
        if(item < currentNode->data) 
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->left;
        }
        else if(currentNode->data < item)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->right;
        }
        else 
        {
             // item == currentNode->data
             return iterator(currentNode);
        }
    }
return end();
 }
```

Comment: Not enough info in your code, but it looks like `*(b2.find(*vit2))` will deference the end iterator if the find function doesn't find anything, which is bad news.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to handle this?
Also, in the second program, even if the string is found in the BST, it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: even if the string is found in the BST, it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: If this isn't homework then just use a `set` or `unordered_set`.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: I suspect that your tree has undefined behaviour somewhere. Where is difficult to guess – it could be your iterator, or it could be that you're storing invalid pointers, or it could be something else.

Comment: @temp Don't reinvent the wheel, `set` and / or `unordered_set` should be able to do everything your `BST` does and more.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(*(b2.find(*vit2)) != *vit) (gives segmentation fault in this line)
```

This mishandles the case where `find` doesn't find anything. If the value isn't found, `find` returns an iterator to one past the end of the container, which you then apply `*` to. Oops.

Comment: Thanks. How do I handle that? can you help me with the code to handle it?

Comment: Also, I get a segmentation fault even when the string is found in the BST

Comment: @temp Compare the results of `find` to `end` before dereferencing them. Also, learn how to troubleshoot a segmentation fault.